# Using python to login to a linux machine and open 2 terminals and execute commands

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, shell

I need to ssh into linux pc and open 2 terminals and execute 2 commands- 1 command in terminal 1 and another command in terminal 2. How should I do this using python scripting?

TIA

Comment: Why do you even need python for that? These commands may give you a headstart: `man ssh`, `man screen`/`man tmux`.

Answer (score 1):

Use paramiko module:
Create connection using paramiko.SSHClient ; then run twice its exec_command method (both will run in different channels <=> two terminals ; you can interact with them in any order you want (write to stdin handles, read from stdout and stderr handles)

EDIT:
for long running commands may be better to use invoke_shell method instead of exec_command

```
import paramiko
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('1.2.3.4', username='user', password='passwd')

shell1 = client.invoke_shell()
shell1.write('cmd\n')

shell2 = client.invoke_shell()
shell2.write('cmd\n')
```

Comment: Can you provide me with an example? in one terminal i will execute a iperf server "iperf -s -u -i1"  and in another terminal I will start iperf client "iperf -c 10.x.x.x -t 10 -i ". How should i go about it?